# xcode Version 11.2.1 storyboard converts 0 constraint to standard

Tags: ios, layout, storyboard, constraints, xcode11.2.1

I am facing a problem in xcode Version 11.2.1 for setting constraints of anything inside of storyboard.

**When I try to put constraint 0, it automatically converts it to the standard. I've attached the screenshot.**

[image]

is there any proper solution to resolve this issue?

I'm attaching another screenshot and want to remove space between these views

[image]

Comment: but i want to set constraint 0 instead of standard. how can i do that?

Comment: Apple update this feature (0 stand for standard)
 Uncheck Constrain to margin

Comment: @SAXENA let me explain you a little bit more. I want to establish two views side by side and don't want to set any space in between. But when I set it to 0 it converts it to standard which results in a little bit spacing between these views (around 8 pixel).

Comment: I've edited my question, now you will be able to see it clearly.

Comment: you can enter 0 in the constant field, it shud be able to take 0 then

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri means to put constraint 0 I will have to click multiple time to reach attribute inspector to make it 0 ?

Comment: Hope they fix this in their next release. @AqeelAhmad

Comment: This is honestly the biggest pain in the ass. Take note that this is how Apple forces you into using their newest toy (SwiftUI). They make not using it more and more frustrating.

Comment: i found if I add 0 and click `Add Constraints` button right away, it doesn't set to `Standard`. It looks it becomes `Standard` when the textfield lose the focus.

Comment: Try inserting -0 instead. Weird but does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple says that this bug will be fixed in Xcode 11.4:

> Fixed a bug that prevented entering a 0 constant in the constraint popup editors. (54076090)

Please, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59465865

Comment: do you have any references to apple documents?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_beta_3_release_notes